# How to compile include_external_msproject() dependencies?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, vcxproj

I am moving our project repo from MSVC project files to CMake. But one special module I want to leave in .vcxproj. This seem to be possible thanks to `include_external_msproject()`. There are a number of issues with this command. But the most stopping is that I need to somehow define dependences.
Well, I use `add_dependencies()`. But it seems to be that CMake doesn't enforce dependent module to bi compiled :(

Is there any way to force dependency compilation?

Answer (score 0):

In the `include_external_msproject` did you list the library dependency at the end? Also are you able to add the dependent library project as a `MODULE`?

I came across this same problem and here's what fixed it for me:

In the library, e.g. mylib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(MyLib MODULE ${SOURCES_${TARGET}} ${HEADERS_${TARGET}})
```

In the project, e.g. myproject/CMakeLists.txt

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -t:restore myproject.vcxproj)

include_external_msproject(
    MyProject myproject.vcxproj
    MyLib)
```